# Don't have enough questions in category to create the question Random

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have 3 categories with several quizzies in it and i can test 2 of them , they work properly, but when i try to test third one i got this error below:

```
There are not enough questions in category XX to create the question Random
```

1. What should i change to get rid of this problem? Seems to be obvious that a user should not be able to add more random questions than the total number of a category, since that there will not be duplicated questions in the quiz.
2. Is this is a known bug?

I can't add more questions on the quiz.

Comment: Grammar cleanup and put the error message into a separate block so it would stand out.

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing moodle_exception('notenoughrandomquestions') when questions not available in the category.
You can find this exception from below path
mod\quiz\locallib.php